# Matching directories in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Directory workspace contains like 5 projects:

```
project-1
project-2
project-3
project-4
project-5
```

I want to match all folders in this directory, but the array does not get populated when I use a variable:

```
workspace="~/workspace";

myDirectories=(${workspace}/project-*/);
```

If I pass it in manually it picks up the directories without a problem.

```
myDirectories=(~/workspace/project-*/);
```

I know it is something simple I am missing, but it is bugging me!

Comment: Are you sure you haven't used any quotes in `workspace` declaration? Otherwise can't reproduce.

Comment: The variables are stored in a .cfg file - and they are key value - and yes they are in quotes. My bad.

Comment: Do you want me to put an answer? If so, use quotes in the example you've provided.

Comment: Yeah you can as you made me realize my fault!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used quotes in `workspace` variable declaration like:

```
workspace="~/workspace"
```

So the `~` won't be expanded as the home directory, but would be treated literally.

You can:

- Leave `~` outside quotes (note that, quotes are not strictly necessary in this case):

  ```
  workspace=~/"workspace"
  ```
- Or use `$HOME` instead of `~`:

  ```
  workspace="$HOME"/workspace
  ```
- Or use absolute paths starting with `/` e.g. `/home/username/workspace`

Comment: `~/workspace` *is* an absolute path; the location it references does not depend on the current working directory.

Comment: @chepner Edited to clarify.

Comment: The third option is very different from the first two. You are hard-coding a single user's home directory, rather than using the home directory of the user actually running the script.

Answer (score 1):

The `~` won't work correctly (expand to user home directory) unless it is unquoted.
As an `*` also needs to be unquoted to expand.

You could define the directory as a fixed string (remove the leading `~`):

```
workspace="workingdirectory"       # or just workspace=workingdirectory
```

And leave all the expansions to the array definition (both work):

```
myDirectories=(       ~/"${workspace}/"project-*/ );
myDirectories=( "${HOME}/${workspace}/"project-*/ );
```

You may use fixed directories like: `"/home/user/$workspace/"project-*/` but in this case you lose the adaptability to any current user running the script without any real gain.
It is also possible to use the `~/` at the time of defining the variable `workspace` but that would also fix the user to the user running that part of the script, which may not be the same as the one doing the directory expansions.
All considered, expanding at the time of creating the array seems to b ethe best solution, and both solutions above work well.